# Validate regex without throwing warning

Tags: php, regex, validation, warnings

I'm trying to validate that a string contains a regular expression, and that it is a valid one in PHP. Usually, I'd do this in the following way

```
<?php
@preg_match($string, '') !== false;
```

That generates a warning, which is fine because we use `@` to suppress it. However, problems arise when we use `set_error_handler` to catch errors, as the handler will still be triggered, despite the `@` supressor.

I'd like to do something similar to the code provided, without it throwing a warning.

**The warning thrown is:**

```
preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Comment: You say "to catch errors", you mean exceptions? If so just wrap the `preg_match` call within a try/catch block.

Comment: preg_match doesn't throw an exception, it just generates a PHP error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this in your error handler:

```
function user_error_handler($severity, $msg, $filename, $linenum, $content) {
    if (0 == (error_reporting() & $severity)) return;
    ...
}
```

In this case, because of the `@` operator, `error_reporting()` will return 0.